# Как передать русский текст из C# to Android

Tags: c#, android

Элементарно, есть русский текст в XML на ПК в C#.

Я его пакую в GSON в строку Json и отправляю через Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text) в бинарном виде по сокету на Андроид.
Но на Андроиде не вижу Юникодового распаковщика из бинарника в строку.

Как мне сделать эту элементарную операцию? Туплю..

Причем туда и обратно? и только в Юникод.. желательно..

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно просто преобразовать байты в строку, то используйте:

```
String str = new String(byteArray,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Где byteArray - собственно массив байтов.

И обратно из строки в байты:

```
byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: а на ПК? оставлять Юникод?

Comment: @VitaliPetrov Да, но в java тогда лучше используйте StandardCharsets.UTF-16.

Comment: 16-й все коверкает в китайский

Comment: и 8-й коверкает.. в общем понятно, мне Юникод именно нужен.

Comment: @VitaliPetrov 1. UTF - это и есть иникод. 

2. Если с UTF-16 у вас что-то коверкает, значит что-то где-то у вас не так. Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text) как раз и выводит в кодировке UTF-16.

3. И ещё, учтите порядок байтов, скорее всего в c# он Little Endian, в java же он наоборот Big Endian.